# How to select each visible day, which are not part of the current visible month?

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I have a problem. I should work with the RichFaces calendar component so I can select each day, which are visible for a current selected month, but that is not possible.

An example:

I selected the month march and now I can see some days of the month February and some day of the month April. And this days i want selected.

I found in the RichFaces Documentation that `boundaryDatesMode` attribute can be controlled but my solution isn't successful. I tried setting this attribute with value "active" or "inactive" but nothing happens.

Can somebody help me to solve my problem?

//EDIT

I work with JSF 1.2 und RichFaces 3.3.3

Sorry, but my english knowledges are not very good.

Comment: Which JSF and RF version are you using? By the way, please use proper English otherwise people wouldn't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no active value in boundaryDatesMode attribute for selecting previous, next months dates.

Write `select` value in attribute `boundaryDatesMode`.

```
<rich:calendar boundaryDatesMode="select" ></rich:calendar>
```

It works for selecting previous and next months dates on current displayed calender popup.